# .call an utility function inside a class to put a reference of an instantiate class into an instance variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to .call an utility function with the class context to instanciate an object from an imported one (inside the calling class):

```
import { setSharedInstances } = require("./utilities");
import TestService = require("./TestService");

class Test {
   constructor() {
      this.services = {};
   }

   getServices() {
       setSharedInstances.call(this, TestService);
   }
}
```

My utilities function looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
   setSharedInstances: (...ServiceClasses) =>
      ServiceClasses.map(ServiceClass =>
         !this.services[ServiceClass.name] && (this.services[ServiceClass.name] = new ServiceClass()))
};
```

My exported TestService looks like this:

```
class TestService {
   constructor() {
      this.gotInstantiated = true;
   }
}
```

But when I execute this code

```
const test = new Test();
test.getServices();
console.log(test.services.TestService.gotInstanciated); //expected to be true
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Test' of undefined in utilities
```

My understanding is that with .call, setSharedInstances will act on services variables declared in the constructor of Test class. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow functions capture `this`. In your utilities if you intend to defer the resolution of `this` to wait until the functions are called then switch the top one out to a classic `function`.

```
setSharedInstances: function (...ServiceClasses) {
    ...
}
```